# How do I connect 1-bit inputs to the selection pin of the 4x16 decoder in Logisim?

Tags: digital-logic

I have four 1-bit input signals (a,b,c,d) coming from 4 separate flip flops. I need to connect them as selectors in a 4x16 decoder. However, the decoder in Logisim only has 1 selection pin, with adjustable bit-widths.

How do I connect the four individual 1-bit signals to a single 4-bit pin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a splitter, which is used to group and separate busses.  The picture shows you how:

[image: Splitter with 4 bits]